# MongoDB - Unrecognized Option: clusterRole

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, sharding, replicaset

I am new to mongodb, this is my second day learning mongodb and trying to setup a sharded cluster.What I did is created virtual boxes of Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS and installed mongodb version 4.2.8. after installing MongoDB on all of my VMs, I updated the mongod.conf file as follows (to configure Config Servers Replica Set, I connected to one of my VMs. I will be implementing 3 replica sets of Config servers)

```
net:
port: 27019
bindIP: 0.0.0.0,192.168.1.22,127.0.0.1

replication:
replSetName: rs01

sharding: 
clusterRole: configsvr
```

after that, I restarted mongodb service using this command

```
sudo systemctl restart mongod
```

and when I try to connect to mongo shell or run this command

```
mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

I get this error "Unrecognized Option: clusterRole". I am following official mongodb documentation on this link https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing indentation in the yaml file. Suboptions need to be indented:

```
net:
    port: 27019
    bindIP: 0.0.0.0,192.168.1.22,127.0.0.1

replication:
    replSetName: rs01

sharding: 
    clusterRole: configsvr
```

Comment: Thanks D.SM for your response. so I did that and this is how my mongod.conf file looks like 
https://ibb.co/5hR5y4j

and after restarting mongod service, when I run the commands it gives me the output as shown in this image
https://ibb.co/C0Kv7RP

Comment: See the server log for clues.

Comment: so here is a new error I am getting now https://ibb.co/JxFgbjR